# Postgress not working

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, database

I'm trying to muck about / familiarise myself with postgres as it's my first time using it.

I've run these commands and you can see the result:

```
postgres-# CREATE USER app_ro WHITE PASSWORD "password"
postgres-# CREATE USER app-rw WITH PASSWORD "password"
postgres-# ALTER USER app-rw WITH PASSWORD "newpassword"
postgres-# CREATE DATABASE kobeat
postgres-# \c kobeat
FATAL:  database "kobeat" does not exist
Previous connection kept
```

My first concern is the commands don't return anything, like in other videos, is this a sign that nothing's happend.

According to the line `FATAL:  database "kobeat" does not exist` the database I create a line up doesn't exist.

I'm running on ubuntu as the postgres account.

Answer (score 3):

You need to terminate your SQL statements with a semicolon `;`. This is required for all your statements except for `\c` which worked.

When you see the prompt as `postgres-#`, it means the statement is not yet completed/executed. After executing your command, you should see the prompt as `postgres=#`.